# C++ Access Protected Member of Templated Struct with Different Template Parameter Values

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, protected

I am creating a templated matrix multiplication function where the returned matrix is a different size than the left-hand-side matrix. In that function I need to access a protected member of the matrix to be returned, but I get compiler error C2248: cannot access protected member. I believe this occurs because the template arguments are different sizes.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t r, std::size_t c>
struct Matrix
{
  template<std::size_t c2>
  Matrix<T, r, c2> operator*(const Matrix<T, c, c2>& rhs);
protected:
  int test;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t r, std::size_t c>
template<std::size_t c2>
Matrix<T, r, c2> Matrix<T, r, c>::operator*(const Matrix<T, c, c2>& rhs)
{
  Matrix<T, r, c2> retMat;
  retMat.test;
  return retMat;
}
```

I tried friending the `operator*()` multiplication function:

```
...
protected:
  int test;
  template<std::size_t c2>
  friend Matrix<T, r, c> Matrix<T, r, c2>::operator*(const Matrix<T, c2, c>& rhs);
};
```

but I get:

```
error C2245: non-existent member function Matrix<T,r,c>::operator * specified as friend (member function signature does not match any overload)
```

How can I access the protected variable in a `Matrix` with different sized template parameter arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot access protected member. I believe this occurs because the template arguments are different sizes.

Exactly: `Matrix<int, 2, 3>` is a different type from (by example) `Matrix<int, 3, 4>`; so inside a method of `Matrix<int, 2, 3>` you can't access the `test` member of `Matrix<int, 3, 4>`.

> I tried friending the `operator*()` multiplication function

It's the right way but you forgot an important element: a `friend` function isn't a method of the class; it's a normal function.

If you implement `operator*()` as method of a class (the wrong way for many reasons), it needs only an explicit parameter (the operand on the right of `*`) because the other element (the operand on the left of `*`) is, implicitly, the `*this` element.

But when you implement `operator*()` as a function (`friend` to the class or not), there isn't the implicit `*this` element; so the function needs **two** parameters.

So is wrong your

```
template<std::size_t c2>
friend Matrix<T, r, c> Matrix<T, r, c2>::operator*(const Matrix<T, c2, c>& rhs);
```

because receive only a parameter and isn't a `Matrix<T, r, c2>::`.

The correct way to solve this problem (IMHO) is a function (not method) as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
Matrix<T, D1, D3> operator* (Matrix<T, D1, D2> const & m1,
                             Matrix<T, D2, D3> const & m2)
 {
   Matrix<T, D1, D3> retMat;
   retMat.test = m1.test + m2.test;
   return retMat;
 }
```

that has to be friend to `Matrix<T, D1, D2>`, `Matrix<T, D2, D3>` and `Matrix<T, D1, D3>`.

You can be temped to define it inside the class

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct Matrix
 {
   protected:
      T test;

      template <typename U, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
      friend Matrix<U, D1, D3> operator* (Matrix<U, D1, D2> const & m1,
                                          Matrix<U, D2, D3> const & m2)
       {
         Matrix<T, D1, D3> retMat;
         retMat.test = m1.test + m2.test;
         return retMat;
       }
 };
```

but this is wrong because cause a multiple definition of the same function in different classes.

So I suggest of *declare* (but not define) the `operator*()` `friend` inside the class

```
template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct Matrix
 {
   protected:
      T test;

      template <typename U, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
      friend Matrix<U, D1, D3> operator* (Matrix<U, D1, D2> const & m1,
                                          Matrix<U, D2, D3> const & m2);
 };
```

and *define* it outside.

The following if a full working example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
struct Matrix
 {
   protected:
      T test;

      template <typename U, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
      friend Matrix<U, D1, D3> operator* (Matrix<U, D1, D2> const & m1,
                                          Matrix<U, D2, D3> const & m2);
 };


template <typename T, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
Matrix<T, D1, D3> operator* (Matrix<T, D1, D2> const & m1,
                             Matrix<T, D2, D3> const & m2)
 {
   Matrix<T, D1, D3> retMat;
   retMat.test = m1.test + m2.test;
   return retMat;
 }

int main ()
 {
   Matrix<long, 2U, 3U> a;
   Matrix<long, 3U, 4U> b;

   auto  c { a * b };

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(c), Matrix<long, 2U, 4U>>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @max66 for answering my question and for tidying up my original post. Can you please explain why when declaring the friend function inside the Matrix struct you have to define a new template parameter typename U instead of reusing T?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the "size", it is about the matrices being of different types.

Changing the template parameters of a class template make that instantiation different from any other instantiation, therefore, one cannot access private/protected members of the other.

In addition, you cannot use friend because you don't know (in advance) the number of columns of the second matrix.

The way to go, IMO, is to make the member public through an accessor.

Good luck!

**Update:**

Look at this function signature:

```
Matrix<T, r, c2> Matrix<T, r, c>::operator*(const Matrix<T, c, c2>& rhs)
```

The type `Matrix<T, c, c2>` is different to the type `Matrix<T, r, c>`, and both of them are also different to the returned type `Matrix<T, r, c2>`.